# How to properly use displacement node in blender?

Tags: displacement

[image]Every time I insert a displacement map in shader node (I plugged in to the height socket and used scale) I only get the flat surface texture , there is no displacement texture to the mesh I'm applying it too. But when i use dispalcement modifier and use the same map it works just fine , so the problem isn't with the map itself. I tried following the tutorial below but the issue remains.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arvhK4tvYuY

Comment: have you enabled Displacement Only in the Properties panel > Material > Settings > Surface > Displacement?

Comment: thank you , I couldn't find the option in eevee render , switched to cycles and it worked just fine.